# Exception when sharing multiple images in messaging using StreamProvider

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, mms, commonsware-cwac

I use [StreamProvider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to serve images to other apps.
Everything works fine except in one case: when I try to share multiple images to messaging app on my Samsung S6 device, Android 5.1.1, the messaging app crash with these logs:

```
Process: com.android.mms, PID: 31790
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'mime_type' does not exist
  at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:78)
  at com.android.mms.ui.aif.a(MessageUtils.java:8184)
  at com.android.mms.util.cf.run(HandleComposerAttachment.java:3251)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Obviously the underlying cursor does not provide a mime_type column.
I'm not sure what I have to do to correctly add this column support.

Additional information:

- I use `USE_LEGACY_CURSOR_WRAPPER`
- If use the following code to share images (where imagesUris contains file content uri):

  ```
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
  shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
  shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  shareIntent.setType("image/*");
  // Start chooser activity
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_send)));
  ```
- It works on my Genymotion emulator on Android 5.1 (issue only on Samsung version?)
- It works if I do not use content URI but file path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure what I have to do to correctly add this column support.

You can't, except by rolling your own `ContentProvider`. I have to adjust `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper` to handle Samsung's bug. Apps receiving `content://` `Uri` values should not assume the existence of a `mime_type` column on a `query()`, largely because there isn't supposed to be one.

*:: sigh ::*

You can track [this issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/issues/9) for this enhancement. I hope to have this out by the end of the week.

Comment: @JérémyReynaud: Try v0.3.1 and see if it helps.

Comment: It fixes the issue. Thanks again for your (very quick) support!

Comment: @JérémyReynaud: Glad to hear that it worked. I was afraid that it would just move the problem somewhere else.

Comment: Had the same fear, so I'm glad too ;-)